# How to get visa at UK border for non-EU citizen accompanying their EU spouse

Tags: borders

My wife has been living and working in the UK since September 2016. I was completed my studies in Poland. I studied in the UK for 3 years but left the country to continue my studies in Poland.

I am a Pakistani national and EU family member. I've had a residence permit card from Poland for 3 years. My wife and I would like to drive from Poland to the UK and I would like to know how I can exercise my freedom of movement rights as I would have to convince the border authorities.

Could you help me with any law? I only saw Article 10 and it is the residence card issued under international EU law.

Can I get a visa at the border if my wife lives in the UK and exercises her treaty rights in the UK? Could you tell me which law applies to my situation as I realise an Article 10 residence card is issued following international EU law and my residence card is national.

I have all the necessary documents to show her employment, funds and our relation.

Please let me know which law reference I can give at the border.

Comment: Just to be clear, your wife is not a UK citizen, right?

Comment: To second the above comment - what nationality is your wife?

Comment: Are you visiting your wife or moving back to the UK? If the latter, you should use the flag icon to ask a moderator to migrate to expats.

Comment: It has been many years but when my sister in law needed a visa (had just started less than 24 hour previous) she was told to go to the nearest capital cities and the consulates there. I have never heard that visa on the border are available now.

Comment: @Willeke EU countries must admit travelers at the border if they fall under freedom of movement.  They must either issue visas at the border to those who require them or admit them without a visa.  I believe the UK takes the second approach, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have no knowledge of what papers OP might need or not need, I just wanted to warn that if a visa is needed, at the border is likely the wrong point to get it. (My sister in law needed that visa before her country joined the EU, so different legal base.)

Comment: Are you planning to move to the UK or are you just going for a short visit to see your wife?

Comment: I would like to move to UK but i am just visiting with my to the UK as she came to visit me to poland . My sister in law is expecting a baby and i want to be in uk to participate in this happines.

Comment: Does it matter if i am planning to stay longer ?

Comment: Hi and can you please try and find this comment story for the EEA family permit refusal as i would like to make my grounds strong . Was he issued with the residence card under national law or article 10 .

 My wife is a polish national working and exercising her rights in UK and i moved from study visa in Uk to poland to continue my study and met my wife and got married religious in berlin on 16 september 2016 , and then official marriage in poland on 20th Jan 2017.

Comment: So phoog you are saying they will admit me without a visa ?

They used to give 1A stamp at the border now they give EEA Dependant Ink stamp .

Comment: @phoog does it matter if i am only accompanying my wife to UK for a visit or wants to move to UK in the future ? Are they going to treat me any different ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this, but the risk of being refused entry will be less if you can secure an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit) before you travel.  (If your family member is a British national who lives in the UK, however, you generally will not qualify for one, because you will not be eligible to enter the UK under the EU freedom of movement regime.)

The UK has implemented the [freedom of movement directive](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616) through [The Immigration (European Economic Area) Regulations 2016](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2016/1052).  These regulations provide in part, at (11)(4), that

> Before an immigration officer refuses admission to the United Kingdom to a person under this regulation because the person does not produce on arrival a document mentioned in paragraph (1) or (2), the immigration officer must ... allow the person to prove by other means that the person is ... (b) a family member of an EEA national with a right to accompany that EEA national or join that EEA national in the United Kingdom;

Accordingly, while you may or may not be issued an EEA family permit at the border, you should indeed be admitted if you have the following (this list is taken from the EEA family permit [documents you must provide](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/documents-you-must-provide) page):

- your passport
- your marriage certificate or other proof of your relationship
- if your wife is with you, her passport or identity card
- If your wife is not with you

  - a copy of her passport or identity card
  - evidence that she is in the UK and

    - has been there for less than three months, or
    - is a "qualified person" (working, studying, or self sufficient)

As your wife has been living in the UK since September 2016, you may be asked to show that she is a qualified person even if you are traveling with her, so it would be wise to bring evidence of her employment with you.

I recall reading on this site a story about a couple who were denied an EEA family permit, but admitted by an officer at juxtaposed border controls in France.  I cannot find it now, perhaps because it was posted in the comments.  As I recall, the person posting the story reported that the immigration officer expressed surprise or dismay at the refusal of the family permit and admitted the couple with no delay.

Comment: could you check the comments or find that story when you can i would like to know the situation and this person could be helpful with his experience

Comment: @Malik unfortunately comments are not searchable on this site.

Answer (score -3):

When your wife is a British citizen or any other country of EU then you will get EEA family permit on the border. Otherwise is not possible.